# Magento 2 - Passing argument from backoffice in Category Layout Update XML field to frontend module or phtml

Tags: magento2, layout, category

In Magento 1 I sometimes used this way to pass an argument to a *category*, directly from the back office

> Category > Custom Design tab > XML Design Update

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setData"><key>giftCardId</key><value>955</value></action>
</reference>
```

Could you tell me what will be the equivalent syntax in Magento 2, Using the same way:

> Category > Design > Layout Update XML

The main idea is to pass a value for a specific category, that could be retrieved in a custom module in frontend.

**Edit:** I know that I can add a custom category attribute to do that too, but the point is really, does an equivalent syntax exists.

Comment: why are you not adding this thing in your module layout xml? you can pass data in block xml and retrieve in template

Comment: @bhargavshastri because i want the magento store owner to change this parameter without my help, and it should be different for different categories

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments in M2

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#argument

Example:

Setting a value of css_class in the [`app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`] layout file:

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
</arguments>
```

Using the value of css_class in [`app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml`]:

```
$cssClass = $this->hasCssClass()
```